# Change collision properties through time

Tags: particles, collision

I've recently started working with blender. For a project i'm working on i would like to visualize evapotranspiration of a park.

My animation starts with nighttime where dew is created (picture 1) where the trees and grass collect particles with a collision.

Picture 1:

[image]

Then during day the trees, grass and water should evaporate particles. But because there is a collision on the trees, the particles will stick to the bottom of the trees... (see red circle picture 2).

Picture 2:

[image]

Question: is there a way to change the properties of the collision after a certain frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many of the values in blender the collision properties can be animated. You can't enable/disable collision entirely but you can change properties such as friction and stickiness so that it is effectively disabled.

Either with the cursor over the value press <kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> and select *Insert Keyframe*, then go to another frame, adjust the value and insert another keyframe.

When changing values in an on/off manner it is common to add keyframes on two neighbouring frames. In the [graph editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html), you will want to change the interpolation type by selecting the keyframes, pressing <kbd>T</kbd> and choosing either vector or constant to prevent value variations between frames.

[image: change interpolation]

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Didn't think it would work this way..